# Javascript "this" pointer in Method Invocation Pattern not pointing to object

Tags: javascript, object, this, method-invocation

I am attempting to use the method invocation pattern in Javascript. I declare a function as an object member.

According to **Javascript: The Good Parts**, this should result in the `this` pointer referencing the enclosing object. When I've tried this before, this has been the case.

In the sample of code below, the `this` pointer reference by the single `console.log` statement is pointing to the *function*, not the object. I've double-checked my code and I honestly don't know what's going on.

I could use another pair of eyes on this. Is there something really obvious that I'm missing here, or am I expecting the wrong behavior? Thank you.

EDIT: I had a mistake in my code that I posted (it's been in flux); the keyword inside the anonymous function should be `that`, not `this`. Fixed.

DOUBLE EDIT: I've added the rest of my code within the module. I'm trying to write a commonJS module (in accordance with the gameJS library that I'm using) and although I'm not sure where that would be the problem, I'm wondering if it is. Does this change anything?

```
var gamejs = require('gamejs');
var system = require('app/system');

var input = {
    eval_keys: function () {
        console.log(this); // This should be the outer object, but shows the function!
        var that = this;
        gamejs.event.get().forEach(function (event) {
            if (event.type === gamejs.event.KEY_DOWN) {
                for (var key in that.keyconfig) {
                    if (that.keyconfig.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (event.key === gamejs.event[key]) {
                            that.keyconfig.key = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                system.log("KEYDOWN", event.key);
            }

            if (event.type === gamejs.event.KEY_UP) {
                for (var key in that.keyconfig) {
                    if (that.keyconfig.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (event.key === gamejs.event[key]) {
                            that.keyconfig.key = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                system.log("KEYUP", event.key);
            }

            return keyconfig;
        });
    },
    eval_mouse: function () {
/* in progress
        else if (event.type === gamejs.event.MOUSE_MOTION) {
            // if mouse is over display surface
            if (display.rect.collidePoint(event.pos)) {
                system.log("mousemove", testcoords);
                testcoords = event.pos;
            }
        }
*/
    },
    keyconfig: {
        K_UP: false,
        K_LEFT: false,
        K_RIGHT: false,
        K_DOWN: false
    }
};

exports.eval_keys = input.eval_keys;
```

Output from Chrome's dev console:

```
Object {eval_keys: function}
eval_keys: function () {
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: I don't see the entry point of your code.... what is getting invoked and where?

Comment: Works just as expected for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YQPF2/), and the output from the console that you've posted tells me it works just as expected for you too, and that `this` is in fact the outer object where you log it to the console. Inside the scope of other functions, `this` will of course reference that scope etc.

Comment: @jondavidjohn I'm calling the function from my main script. I'm importing it there as a commonJS module. (I've updated my post to reflect that, in case that's causing some issue in some way.) However, I would expect that, upon object creation, the `this` pointer should show me all of my methods...

Comment: Probably you're calling it wrong, after `exports.eval_keys = input.eval_keys;` you probably are not calling it as a method on `input` any more. Try `exports.eval_keys = input.eval_keys.bind(input);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/guypursey/hfecB/) to me, by calling `input.eval_keys()` after the object is declared.

Also the output you show in the console looks to me to be the output you want -- i.e., the outer object `Object {eval_keys: function}` containing the method.

The problem seems more to be that you should be seeing the other methods you declared in there, like this:

```
Object {eval_keys: function, eval_mouse: function, keyconfig: Object}
eval_keys: function () {
eval_mouse: function () {
keyconfig: Object
__proto__: Object
```

So, as far as I can tell, your question should be "why aren't these other methods showing up within my object in the console?" But I don't what else you are doing with the code that might account for that nor how and when you're invoking the relevant method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect the fact that this is a CommonJS module using the `exports` keyword. I didn't think it was relevant, but maybe there's something I don't know. For reference, I'm importing this module with `require` in my main.js file and calling the function from there.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also show what you do to then call that method in your main script?

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you didn't use an anonymous function with that [`forEach` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has a different value inside there. You can pass it in a the second parameter:

```
gamejs.event.get().forEach(function (event) {
    // this now refers to the outer this
}, this);
```

Alternatively you can use your `that` variable which refers to the outer `this` value as well.

Comment: Whoops - sorry, my code is in progress. The `this` keyword in the inner function should actually be `that`. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what was causing the `this` pointer to only show an object with one function - it was this line:

```
exports.eval_keys = input.eval_keys;
```

On a whim, I decided to add `exports.keyconfig = input.keyconfig` and it appeared in the console as part of the object.

It looks like the `exports` keyword does something with the `this` pointer when it's referenced, even if the `this` pointer is inside the module in question. I'm not exactly sure how that worked, but it did.

I'm running into more problems, but at the moment, the immediate issue has been resolved. I'll have to do some more reading on this.